# How to configure SSL certificate inside my docker container?

Tags: python, django, docker, ssl

I have a django application that running inside a docker container. However, while the application works perfectly fine inside my local PC when running inside the container it is unable to make any requests such as calling certain APIs or even `pip install`. All of these actions will throw an error like `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)`.

Only way I got `pip install` working is to do `RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`

Solutions tried:

- Copying my local `rootCA.pem` file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` in the container
- `RUN update-ca-certification`
- Tried different python providers (`alpine`, `buster`, `slim-buster`)

There are many more I couldn't remember

I don't want to just turn verify off as it is bad practice so I'm trying to keep verification on. I have included my `Dockerfile` below.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.2-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates

COPY certs/rootCA.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

RUN update-ca-certificates

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: Are you deploying your container in an environment where there is an SSL inspecting firewall or a proxy?

Comment: @Selcuk If I understand OPs post correctly, the problem occurs at build time

Comment: Apologies if I didn't make it clear enough. The image builds successfully and the container runs with my application. However certain function in my application requires calling of APIs. That's where it goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

You may try a few things. First, verify the permissions of rootCA.pem . If it can not be accessed by the user running the application process inside the container, ssl verification would fail. (you can try `RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rootCA.pem`)

Another thing you can do is to verify the certificate chain using openssl:

```
openssl verify -CAfile <full_path_of_rootCA.pem> <full_path_of_certificate.pem>
```

Here is an example:
`openssl verify -CAfile certs/rootCA.pem certs/certificate.pem`

Comment: I can confirm that rootCA.pem permission is verified and after typing that in my container console, /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/rootCA.pem: OK is returned. However, issue is still not solved